Performance of SYCL against OpenCV
I am comparing the performance of gaussian filter with sycl on Nvidia V100 vs existing opencv implementation on CPU.
Kernel Size: 15
Image Size: 6000 x 6000 pixels
Platform: Nvidia V100 GPU (using SYCL)
Comparison: OpenCV implementation on CPU
Average execution time over 10 iterations:
SYCL: 0.0481176 seconds (so around half time for data transfer, host to device and device to host.)
Also I tried USM.
OpenCV: 0.0492393 seconds
However still opencv's performance is better thatn SYCL on GPU. Here is the full code.
Can you please guide ??

void gaussian_filter(sycl::queue &q, cv::Mat &input, cv::Mat &output, int kernel_size, double sigma) {
    int width = input.cols;
    int height = input.rows;
    int half_kernel = kernel_size / 2;

    // Compute the 1D Gaussian kernel
    std::vector<float> kernel = compute_gaussian_kernel(kernel_size, sigma);

    // Allocate device buffers
    buffer<uchar, 2> input_buf(input.data, range<2>(height, width));
    buffer<uchar, 2> output_buf(output.data, range<2>(height, width));
    buffer<float, 1> kernel_buf(kernel.data(), range<1>(kernel.size()));

    // Submit kernel for horizontal pass
    q.submit([&](handler &h) {
        auto input_access = input_buf.get_access<access::mode::read>(h);
        auto output_access = output_buf.get_access<access::mode::write>(h);
        auto kernel_access = kernel_buf.get_access<access::mode::read>(h); // Create kernel access here

        h.parallel_for(range<2>(height, width), [=](id<2> idx) {
            int x = idx[1];
            int y = idx[0];

            float sum = 0.0f;
            for (int kx = -half_kernel; kx <= half_kernel; ++kx) {
                int xk = std::clamp(x + kx, 0, width - 1);
                sum += input_access[y][xk] * kernel_access[kx + half_kernel];
            }
            output_access[y][x] = static_cast<uchar>(sum);
        });
    }).wait();

    // Submit kernel for vertical pass
    q.submit([&](handler &h) {
        auto input_access = output_buf.get_access<access::mode::read>(h); // Read from the output of horizontal pass
        auto output_access = output_buf.get_access<access::mode::write>(h);
        auto kernel_access = kernel_buf.get_access<access::mode::read>(h); // Create kernel access here

        h.parallel_for(range<2>(height, width), [=](id<2> idx) {
            int x = idx[1];
            int y = idx[0];

            float sum = 0.0f;
            for (int ky = -half_kernel; ky <= half_kernel; ++ky) {
                int yk = std::clamp(y + ky, 0, height - 1);
                sum += input_access[yk][x] * kernel_access[ky + half_kernel];
            }
            output_access[y][x] = static_cast<uchar>(sum);
        });
    });
}

void profile_gaussian_filter(int iterations, const std::string &image_path) {
    // Load the image
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (input.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat output(input.size(), input.type());

    // Set kernel size and sigma for Gaussian filter
    int kernel_size = 15;
    double sigma = 4.0;

    // Create SYCL queue
    sycl::queue q{sycl::default_selector_v};

    // Measure performance of SYCL Gaussian filter
    double total_time_sycl = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        auto start_sycl = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        gaussian_filter(q, input, output, kernel_size, sigma);
        q.wait();
        auto end_sycl = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        total_time_sycl += std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end_sycl - start_sycl).count();
    }
    std::cout << "Average SYCL Gaussian filter time over " << iterations << " iterations: " 
              << (total_time_sycl / iterations) << " ms" << std::endl;

    // Measure performance of OpenCV Gaussian blur
    double total_time_opencv = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        auto start_opencv = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cv::GaussianBlur(input, output, cv::Size(kernel_size, kernel_size), sigma);
        auto end_opencv = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        total_time_opencv += std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end_opencv - start_opencv).count();
    }
    std::cout << "Average OpenCV Gaussian blur time over " << iterations << " iterations: " 
              << (total_time_opencv / iterations) << " ms" << std::endl;

    // Write output images
    cv::imwrite("output_sycl.png", output);
    cv::imwrite("output_opencv.png", output);
}

